# Removing views when switching tabs using UITabBarController ( iOS SDK )

Tags: ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I have 4 tabs in UITabBarController (for convenience I name it "tab A", "tab B", etc here)

Initially, tab A is selected. the View Controller contains a button which can add another view to screen by :

```
SomeViewController *vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 431);
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
```

Of course, the view is showing as expected. My question is:

How can I remove the newly-added subview when I switch to tab B? in other words, how can I remove the subview when switching back to tab A, just like never call out the subview ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to record the UIView popped-up in the View Controller, and when the tab is going to switch, remove those views from superview.